# Why do some renderings appear twice in Stats.aspx admin page

Tags: admin-pages

I'm using the Stats.aspx (http://hostname/sitecore/admin/stats.aspx) admin page to identify the slowest components in my solution.

For some components, I see two entries e.g.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------------+-------------+
|                                                  Rendering                                                   | Avg. time (ms) | Avg. items | Max. time | Max. items |    Total time    | Total items |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------------+-------------+
| Gallery (/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/MySolution/Media/Gallery)                                       |       306.3429 |        159 |  915.2689 |        469 | 00:00:00.9190289 |         479 |
| Controller: MySolution.Feature.Media.Controllers.GalleryController,MySolution.Feature.Media. Action: Gallery |       305.3223 |       9386 |  913.6628 |      28061 | 00:00:00.9159670 |       28158 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+------------+-----------+------------+------------------+-------------+
```

The first is the path to the Rendering definition item, whereas the second is the assembly namespace/class of the controller for that same component. Why does the stats page represent the same thing twice and which one represents the true values?

Comment: Are you loading the rendering via a controller rendering?

Comment: Hmm possibly. I've seen that on a few other renderings...

Comment: And the other renderings are also from controller rendering?

Comment: Yes, almost everything is done with controller renderings.

Comment: So, I think this is why you are having 2 entries. I'll try to dig into this later and see why this is happening. What sitecore version are you using?

Comment: Using Sitecore 9.0 update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my investigation, the statistics of the rendering is added during the execution of the `<mvc.renderRendering>` pipeline. The method `RecordStatistic` is called at the end.

So, for every rendering being rendered on the page, Sitecore is adding the statistics
so duplicate should not be present.

However, what may happened is that if you have 2 renderings: 1 controller rendering and 1 normal rendering, it may be that on some items you are using the rendering directly while on other items it may be the controller rendering.